# How to remove extra lines in the table cell of Jface table

Tags: jface

Im using OneDrawLabelProvider to display multiline text in Jface table, but all the rows are of same height even for the ones which does not have multiline, how do I remove remove extra lines for the cells that does not have multilines?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JFace / SWT tables always have rows of the same height.

Eclipse Nebula [NatTable](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html) does support different row heights.

Comment: IIRC the statement that SWT tables only support one row height is only correct for Windows, because the native table in Windows brings in the limitation. On Linux different row heights are supported.
But yes, NatTable provides this OS independent.

Comment: @DirkFauth Different heights don't work on macOS either.